# How do I fix my wireless network that frequently disconnects and is inconsistent? (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, disconnect

I recently built my desktop and am new to linux. I wanted to try it out and am generally satisfied, but I am experiencing inconsistent internet disconnects. Sometimes it will be about once every few minutes but it's at the very least once an hour. Most of the time it quickly reconnects within ten seconds. I'm using a wireless connection as I am not able to connect to the router through a cable.

I've been reading up on this issue a fair amount and tried a few fixes that were ineffective, so I'm assuming someone will need at least this piece of information:

```
iwconfig

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"DDC78"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 18:1B:EB:**:**:**   
          Bit Rate=52 Mb/s   Tx-Power=27 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=52/70  Signal level=-58 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:2347  Invalid misc:6808   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Please let me know if you need more information, and thank you for your responses.

Comment: which version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: also, what kind of security does the network have?

Comment: "What's your Ubuntu question? Be specific" sorry? Make that a real title please.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I first installed 14.04 I was having the same issue and have never had this problem with Ubuntu before. Updating the kernels eventually seemed to fixed the issue for me. You can make sure you are completely up to date by executing the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: I've seen that before... Any easy "kernel-only" update? And wondering, does dist-upgrade only update 14.04 to the latest LTS (stays LTS), or does it upgrade to 14.10/newer?

Comment: @Xen2050 No, this brings all your software for 14.04 LTS up to date (all the bug fixes, security updates etc). Dist-upgrade updates everything including serious stuff like system drivers and kernels. If you are using Ubuntu for production, a simple upgrade without using the "dist-" prefix will not update system drivers and the linux kernel so that you can receive stuff like security patches without impacting stability and allows the user to opt for the dist-upgrade (which may impact stability) whenever it is most convenient. `apt-get update` updates the list of packages to upgrade/ no install.